# Does giving Miranda Alliance resources change anything?

Tags: mass-effect-3

*minor spoilers ahead*

After some time into the game...

> Miranda wants to talk to you in the apartments in the Citadel. When you meet her, she asks for Alliance resources for some task that she can't specify. You have the option to decline (renegade) or accept (paragon).
> Does this choice have any repercussions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Miranda will ask to see Shepard personally at the private apartments at the presidium commons at the citadel. At this point, give Miranda the Alliance resources she needs to find her sister Oriana. This is the end of personal contact with Miranda until the Priority: Horizon mission.

If you don't help her she won't proceed in her quest, otherwise you'll see her again at Priority:Horizon